# Distributed caching for Mybatis

Tags: java, mybatis, distributed-caching, terracotta, hazelcast

Anyone had production experience with distributed caching for Mybatis? I saw some suggestions for ehcache/Terracotta, but previous experience with Terracotta would make me want to stay away from it (complex to configure and keep running). Hazelcast seems like an interesting possibility - anyone tried using it as a distributed cache with Mybatis?

Our app has a relatively large database (1TB), so we'd like a solution which scales well.

Answer (score 4):

At MyBatis, we already released a [MyBatis/Hazelcast bridge module](http://www.mybatis.org/caches/hazelcast/).

Comment: Thanks, Simone! We'll try it out and provide feedback

Comment: Simone - what are the criteria for choosing between OSCache, memcached and Hazelcast? We obviously want performance, reliability, efficiency - can you give any recommendations between the caches which mybatis supports? For instance, I can imagine that the single-point of failure issues are different since Hazelcast distributes redundant copies of the cache across all nodes (but presumably requires additional resources for this)...

Answer (score 1):

I have been using Ehcache with Mybatis+Spring for production and its very effective.
And its configuration is pretty simple. (hardly 10 lines xml file)

On personal level my Suggestion would be using Ehcache.

**PS :** I do use hazelcast for diff purpose which requires distributed caching and its great too but for MyBatis it's like shooting an Insect with Gun.!

Answer (score 0):

I am using Redis for cluster caching. Totally I have 5 nodes running on it and cache is never the bottleneck.

The official plugin https://github.com/mybatis/redis-cache works well but lack of efficiency, I improved it a little bit with cluster support and more efficient timeout control https://github.com/MiltonLai/redis-cache